# JEB Community Edition - Difference between Script vs Plugin?

Tags: jeb

I've downloaded JEB CE (community edition) and according to the [feature matrix](https://www.pnfsoftware.com/jeb/#features-matrix), it supports both script and plugin functionality:

[image]

I would like to know if there is any difference in the 2 and any advantage of using one over the other? In version 5.X+, there is a /coreplugins folder which shows plugins written in both Python and Java:

[image]

A Java plugin :

```
import com.pnfsoftware.jeb.core.Version;
import com.pnfsoftware.jeb.core.units.code.asm.decompiler.ast.opt.AbstractCOptimizer;

/**
 * A sample gendec AST optimizer plugin.
 * 
 * @author Nicolas Falliere
 *
 */
public class COptSampleJava extends AbstractCOptimizer {

    public COptSampleJava() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int perform() {
        logger.debug("COptSampleJava: the optimizer is running");
        return 0;
   }
}
```

would look identical to the Python version

```
from com.pnfsoftware.jeb.core.units.code.asm.decompiler.ast.opt import AbstractCOptimizer

'''
Skeleton for an Java Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) optimizer plugin for gendec, JEB's generic decompiler.
This Python plugin is executed during the decompilation pipeline of a method.

How to use:
- Drop this file in your JEB's coreplugins/scripts/ sub-directory
- Make sure to have the setting `.LoadPythonPlugins = true` in your JEB's bin/jeb-engines.cfg file

For additional information regarding dexdec AST optimizer plugins, refer to:
- the Manual (www.pnfsoftware.com/jeb/manual)
- the API documentation: TODO
'''
class COptSamplePython(AbstractCOptimizer):
  # note: Python script optimizers are singleton instances!
  # the engine will instantiate and provide a single instance for all decompilation threads
  # therefore, if you are using object attributes, make sure to provide support for concurrency
  # (this restriction does not apply to Java script optimizers, as well as full-blown jar optimizers;
  # each decompilation thread has its own unique instance of such optimizer objects)
  # for this reason (as well as others), moderately complex AST optimizers should be written in Java

  def __init__(self):
    self.logger.debug('COptSamplePython: instantiated')

  def perform(self):
    self.logger.debug('COptSamplePython: executed')

    # if a value >0 is returned, the decompiler will assume that AST is being transformed and this AST optimizer will be called again
    return 0  # no optimization is performed
```

Can both languages be used for both plugin and script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://www.pnfsoftware.com/jeb/manual/dev/introducing-jeb-extensions/#scripts-vs-plugins).

Scripts...

> - Implement IScript
>
> 1. Example: modify some code, navigate somewhere, display some info,
>    etc.

> - Are called by users to achieve small tasks
> - Must be written in Python (they are run in a Jython VM)
>
> 2. Ideal for rapid development and prototyping

> - Are executed by JEB on-demand
>
> 3. In the GUI client, can be executed via the File menu

Plugins...

> - Implement a specialized sub-type of IPlugin
> - Can perform a variety of tasks, from input processing, disassembling, decompiling, adding functionality to other plugins,
>   event-triggered actions, etc.
> - May be compiled as jar; some plugin types may be written as scripts (Java or Python)

Hope this reference is useful too all who use this software package.